# MySQL You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

When I run this query

```
update Apply 
set major='CSE'
where major='EE' and sID in (select sID from Student
                             where GPA >= all (select GPA from Student
                       where sID in (select sID from Apply
                             where major='EE')));
```

it returns an error: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'Apply' for update in FROM clause. But it succeeds in another MySQL.

if I add "as tmp" to the end of the code, it returns an error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as tmp' at line 6

Can somebody tell me the reason and how can I modify the code?
Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Problem: You're referencing the table `Apply` twice in two different contexts.

Solution: Give them different aliases, e.g. `Apply as a1` and `Apply as a2`

(Maybe this also needs to be done for `Student`)